# Route 53 - site cannot be reached error on wifi

Tags: amazon-web-services, browser, amazon-route53

I have a web app where requests hit route53 --> elastic load balancer --> ec2 that is hosted in the Northern Virginia region. Probably 95% of users are able to access my app just fine. However, I have a handful of users who report they cannot access the app when they are on wifi. Instead, they get a "This site can't be reached" error in their browser. The common theme I've noticed is that these users are all outside of Virginia. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this or what steps I can take to troubleshoot? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll need to determine whether the problem is with the DNS resolution, or with their network connectivity. Get them to resolve the DNS Name (eg using `nslookup` or even just `ping`) to see whether it resolves to an IP address. Also get them to try accessing via the Elastic Load Balancer's URL (instead of your Route 53 domain name) to confirm that network connectivity is working. You can then hopefully identify where the problem lies.

Comment: thanks, i'll def try those out!